# WSO2 EI with ELK integration not working as expected

Tags: wso2, kibana, filebeat

I followed instructions at [Publish WSO2 Carbon logs to Logstash/Elasticsearh/Kibana (ELK) using Log4j SocketAppender](https://udaraliyanage.wordpress.com/2016/06/19/publish-wso2-carbon-logs-to-logstashelasticsearhkibana-elk-using-log4j-socketappender/) but it is not working and I didn't see any logs in the kibana dashboard.

Can somebody please help me the correct configuration of xxxx.conf file?

Comment: Improved link formatting.

Comment: Tag kibana added.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't follow this approach for my ELK integration. I simply used filebeat on wso2 server, then I add wso2carbon.log file as an input then you can forward it to either logstash or directly elastic

A sample filebeat config

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /srv/wso2/wso2ei-6.1.1/repository/logs/app*.log
  document_type: wso2-logs
  scan_frequency: 30s
  fields:
    application: wso2-ei
#for logstash
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
#for elastic
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["myelastichost:9200"]
```

Then your logstash template will depend on the format of your logs

Comment: Thank so much for your answer, followed same able to see logs in kibana. Now i am struggling with Kibana dashboard creation can you help me on this?

Comment: I think that this should be another question, but what is your issue exactly ?

Comment: I need to create dashboards in kibana using wso2 logs, But don't know how to create, any documentation? or best practices.

Comment: Then it's nothing related to wso2, i guess it's standard features of ELK, you have to create a search query, save it, then a visualization based on this search query and finally add this graph, table, figure... to your dashboard.

Comment: Yes its nothing related WSO2 now, Any sample search query if have already available please share me, mean while i will try to create my own

Comment: It's difficult to answer this, you should rather follow the getting started tutorial from elk : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/getting-started.html. It's rather straightforward to build a search, you can select your filter on the left side of the screen and then simply save your query on the top right. But I think this discussion should stop here as it as nothing to do with the initial topic, you should really open another question and accept (or not) the answer if it fixed your first question.